# Seeing only the commits not in another branch in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-cherry

I am using TortoiseGit 1.8.3.0.  I would like to study what changes were done in a given branch.  On the command line, I would checkout this branch and launch `git cherry -v origin/master`, which would give me the list of commits in the current branch that are not in master.

How can I do the same in TortoiseGit?  I imagine there would be a way to filter the log window so that it would only show these commits...

I was given a pointer to [this tortoisegit bug report](https://tortoisegit.org/issue/832). It implies I should be able to do this since version 1.8.2, but I didn't find how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Update to latest version of TortoiseGit
2. Open Log dialog
3. Click on the blue label (the branch indicator) in the left upper corner -> the browse references dialog opens
4. Select the two branches you want to compare
5. Click on "OK" -> a menu appears, select the "..." entry there